# pointer to struct in struct in c

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, struct

I have trouble with structures in c.

I have two structures like

```
typedef struct
{
    char isim[256];
    int deger;
    struct ekstra *sonra;
}ekstra;

typedef struct
{
    char *name;
    int val;
    struct ekstra *next;
}node;

/*and main is*/

int main()
{
    int i;
    node dizi[12];

    for(i=0;i<12;i++)
    {
        dizi[i].name = malloc("asdasd"*sizeof(int));
        strcpy (dizi[i].name,"asdasd");
        /*and trouble starts here*/
        **dizi[i].next = malloc(sizeof(ekstra));
        printf("%s",dizi[i].next->isim);**
    } 
}
```

the error is

> error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

How can I hold place for `dizi[i].next`?

Comment: Welcome. I think you should edit your question so the code is printed appropriately.

Comment: You allocate space for an entire struct when really you just need a pointer to that struct, also even though you allocate space you never assign it a value. Also, format your code; someone else shouldn't have to.

Comment: That code doesn't compile. I get the following error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct ekstra ekstra’

Comment: are these `**` part of the actual code?

Answer (score 8):

`struct ekstra` is not the same as `ekstra`.

Your first struct typedef should be declared as follows:

```
typedef struct ekstra
{
    char isim[256];
    int deger;
    struct ekstra *sonra;
}ekstra;
```

Answer (score 0):

> typedef struct... ekstra;

This means: "create a type that is called ekstra". From now on this type can be used just as any variable type (int, char etc).

> struct ekstra *next;

This means: Somewhere in my program there is a struct of some type, I don't know what it contains, but I want to point to an element of that type. This is the meaning of *incomplete type*.

To fix your problems, simply replace this row with `ekstra *next;`.

---

More comments not directly related to the question:

> dizi[i].name = malloc("asdasd"*sizeof(int));

This is pure nonsense code. It means: "Create a constant string literal in the ROM part of my program. In this constant string literal, store the letters "asdasd" and a null termination character. Then take the *address* of this ROM memory location, which is completely irrelevant to my application, convert it to an integer so that I get a 32-bit nonsense number. Then multiply this nonsense number with the sizeof an int, which doesn't make any sense to anyone either. Then take this completely nonsense result and allocate a random amount of dynamic memory based on this. Then watch the program crash.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand code line like

```
malloc("asdasd"*sizeof(int));
```

But, I think you problem should slove like this

```
dizi[i].next = (ekstra *)malloc(sizeof(ekstra));
```

and you struct define should like

```
typedef struct node{
    int a;
    int b;
    struct node *next;
}node;
```

Comment: -1 for teaching to typecast the result of malloc in C. Read [this](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: @Lundin - Actually, my compiler gives an compile error if the cast isn't there: error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'ekstra *' Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast.  I'm using Visual Studio 2008 C++ compiler though. Does it make a difference if you are using native C compiler?

Comment: @dcp Indeed, C and C++ are very different in this case. C allows implicit function prototypes of malloc and it doesn't have the strict type checking of C++, which caused your compiler error. Don't compile C code with a C++ compiler.